# Issue in calculation of values in all text fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, onblur

I am implementing MVC application in which I am trying to dynamically calculate and display the calculation of all tr element whenever a user enters the value of `Count` field. I have static values coming from-

```
public class Adjustment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Pieces { get; set; }
    public int Count{ get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var adjustments = from adjustment in AddAdjustment() select adjustment;
    ViewBag.AdjustmentList = adjustments;
    return View();
}

private List<Adjustment> AddAdjustment()
{
    List<Adjustment> AdjustmentList = new List<Adjustment>();
    Adjustment oAdjustment = new Adjustment();
    oAdjustment.Id = 1;
    oAdjustment.Size = 10;
    oAdjustment.Pieces = 12;
    oAdjustment.Count = 2;
    AdjustmentList.Add(oAdjustment);
    oAdjustment = new Adjustment();
    oAdjustment.Id = 2;            
    oAdjustment.Size = 20;           
    oAdjustment.Pieces = 11;
    oAdjustment.Count = 1;
    AdjustmentList.Add(oAdjustment);
    return AdjustmentList;
}
```

**My jQuery code is-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Count').blur(function()
        {
            var count = $('#Count').val();
            var bundalSize = $('#BundalSize').text();
            var totalPieces = count*bundalSize;
            $('#Pieces').val(totalPieces);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**and here is my table-**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Bundal Size
        </th>
         <th>
            Count
        </th>
         <th style="border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick;">
            Pieces
        </th>           
        <th>
            Count
        </th>
        <th>
            Pieces
        </th>         
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AdjustmentList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;" id="BundalSize">
               @item.Size
            </td>        
            <td style="width:90px;">
               @item.Count
            </td>
            <td style="width:180px; border-right:solid #e8eef4 thick;">
              @item.Pieces
            </td>
            <td>    
                  <input id="Count" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" />
            </td>
            <td>    
                  <input id="Pieces" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled />
            </td>             
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I am trying to calculate multiplication on `blur` event ,it results only for first record in table. I want to calculate it on each `id="Count"` for each record. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: id is unique in html page. you can't assign same id to multiple elements. if you assign same id for multiple elements, js only take the first element. you can use class for that...

Comment: If this is the issue,then how to make calculation using dynamic id?

Comment: use class for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id` like,

```
<td style="width:100px;" class="BundalSize">
     @item.Size
</td> 
<td>    
    <input class="Count" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" />
</td>
<td>    
    <input class="Pieces" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled />
</td>
```

Change your `jquery code` like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Count').blur(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr');// for current row
        var count = parseFloat($(this).val()); // use parseInt if integer
        var bundalSize = parseFloat($parent.find('.BundalSize').text());
        var totalPieces = count*bundalSize;
        $parent.find('.Pieces').val(totalPieces);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1...you can use `+` instead of `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`. `+` will carry the data type. like this,
`var count = +$(this).val(); // use parseInt if integer

 var bundalSize = +$parent.find('.BundalSize').text();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` instead of `foreach` and append the value of the counter `i` to the ids

```
<td style="width:100px;" id="BundalSize@i">
....
<input id="Count@i" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" onblur="Calc('@i');" />
....
<input id="Pieces@i" type="text" style="width:100px ;height:15px ;margin:1px" disabled />

....

<script type="text/javascript">
function Calc(IndexVal) {
    var count = $('#Count' + IndexVal).val();
    var bundalSize = $('#BundalSize' + IndexVal).text();
    var totalPieces = count * bundalSize;
    $('#Pieces' + IndexVal).val(totalPieces);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using parseFloat:

```
var bundalSize = parseFloat($('#BundalSize').text());
```